# Copy Chart Series Data To Another Chart

Tags: c#, charts, copy, series

I have a chart using the Chart control which has 4 series with a bunch of lines.

How would i copy all the series to a second chart? Programmatically, of course.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this, but I think you can do this:

```
foreach (var series in sourceChart.Series)
    destinationChart.Series.Add(series);
```

Comment: ok i see, no idea why i didn't think of that! i'll give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

I did it in this way:

```
foreach (Series ser in sourceChart.Series)
            {
                ser.Name += "New";
                destinationChart.Series.Add(ser);    
            }
```

You have to rename Series